# Roll back Sharepoint Products Configuration

Tags: installation, content-database, configuration-wizard

I've performed a standard installation and run the Sharepoint Products Configuration Wizard.

I've realized too late that the wizard wasn't asking me for info like Central Admin Content DB name, which now is ... I'd rather switch to a powershell configuration.

Can I roll back the Sharepoint Products Configuration?

I haven't started the configuration of the farm yet. I know that I can rename the content db by backup/restoring it but I was looking for something cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you create the configuration database - you create the "farm".  So in this case you want to create a new "farm".

Re-run the wizard and disconnect from the farm.  Then Delete your existing databases.  Now you can start from 0.

Answer (score 2):

If you run the Configuration wizard one of the server in the farm, it will create the Config DB and Admin DB for Central admin( ugly name with GUID), you cant roll back it.

Only thing is re run the config wizard and disconnect the server to farm( all the server which already joined to the farm), once you will do this, it will delete everything...Now check on SQL server and clean the database if those are still their.

Now you can run the command line wizard again and create new server farm.